# Thinkpad Bluetooth turns itself on upon restart/hibernate

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, thinkpad

I have a T400 with Windows 7 64bit. About 3 weeks ago, the Lenovo update pushed a Bluetooth update that added a 2.1 driver and device experience. Since then, my bluetooth turns itself on whenever the OS comes up (full restarts as well as waking from hibernation). I can turn it of using the `<Fn>`+`<F5>` Radio menu, but it just turns itself on again the next time. If I forget to turn it off, it just eats my battery that much faster.

I've been scouring the web and couldn't find similar occurrences. Is this a hardware issue, a BIOS issue (although no reference to BT in any of the BIOS menus), a driver issue or (shudder) a user issue?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with a Lenovo BIOS update... to some degree. Still occurs every once in a while. I've grown to believe it's faulty hardware. Learning to accept something you don't understand is hard :)

Answer (score 0):

1. open the services control applet (start > run > services.msc) and disable the bluetooth service (right click > properties).
2. download and run **[Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)** and disable bluetooth related startup entries.

*Autoruns is freeware.*

Comment: I've already used a startup monitoring app and none of the ones in there have anything to do with bluetooth. As for disabling the service - I do want to use bluetooth - but on my own terms. I set the 2 services ("Bluetooth services" and "Bluetooth Support services") to Manual - but something still triggers the first. Again, this appeared after a driver update - so I'm looking for a Thinkpad-specific solution.

Comment: gotcha. that's what i like about ASUS machines, their Tray Utility turns off bluetooth, webcam etc, and the device will STAY off until you change the status. not sure know if DevCon will do you any good,  but it's worth a try: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272

Comment: Thanks for the tool Molly, never heard of it before, +1 on the comment. Unfortunately, the BT turns itself on BEFORE it even reaches Windows - yet there's no option in the BIOS screens to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

Check this linke [Lenovo BT off](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/T61-and-prior-T-series-ThinkPad/Bluetooth-radio-defaults-to-Off-state/td-p/169151/page/1)

Do the opposite from this solution, e.g. instead of setting it to on, set it to off.

Comment: Could you summarize the solution in your answer?  Links often go dead and another user in the future may need the information.

Comment: Summarize andyou will get an upvote from me, it seems like the Lenovo forum should solve the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Enter BIOS (ThinkVantage when pc is turning on and then F1).
Go to the Security tab and then I/O Port Access.
There you can disable Bluetooth.

If you cant find such options, try updating BIOS first.